# Inserting two datafields into a single datafield in PostGis that are the same projection

Tags: postgresql, gis, postgis

I am still very new to the world of GIS, so bear with me.

I have a one single datafield for my ESTR89 / UTM 32N / SRID 25832 column in PostGis. E.g. with a value of 0101000020E8640000C573D4301A122641113FF122C5965741

I am working against a webservice in order to import new data, but my data suplier has two columns. E.g. with a value of 6174030,866 and 724162,419

The issue is that the specification of the webservice also says that its two columns are ESTR89 / UTM 32N / SRID 25832.

I am somewhat stumped as to how I am going to create an INSERT statement for PostGIS that combines or transforms the two columns into a single column ‐ and of course if I am missing or misunderstanding something about this.

I have been looking at [st_transform](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/ST_Transform.html), but I cannot seem to got a handle on this.

PostGIS info : "POSTGIS="1.3.3" GEOS="3.0.0-CAPI-1.4.1" PROJ="Rel. 4.6.0, 21 Dec 2007" USE_STATS"

Any hint or nudge in the right direction would be nice. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem right, wwhat you want to do is ceating a point from x and y coordinates and insert that point in your table with a point column.

so what you do is that you create the point with st_makepoint like this, assuming the field of the x coordinate is xfld and the field of the y coordinate is yfld in your import table:
st_makepoint(xfld,yfld)

/Nicklas

Comment: I managed to figure this one out before I saw your post :
  
  SELECT st_geomfromtext('POINT(6174030.866 724162.419)', 25832) // returns "0101000020E8640000448B6CB7538D5741022B87D684192641"

but yours is doing something simlilar :

SELECT st_makepoint(6174030.866,724162.419) // returns "0101000000448B6CB7538D5741022B87D684192641"
  
  It returns a geom, the one above lets me control which projection to use. :-)

Comment: yes you are right. geomfromtext lets you specify the srid of the point. with st_makepoint youneed to use st_setsrid to specify it. the pro of using st_makepopint in your case is that you have to construct the wkt-string if using geomfromtext something like: st_geomfromtext(POINT('||xfld||' '||yfld||')',25832). and the alternative is st_setsrid(st_makepoint(xfld,yfld),258323)